# What attributes, criteria, or other factors can be used to measure to health of a political party?

Tags: parties

Looking at political parties objectively, is there any way to externally assess the health of such an organization?

Some examples could be leadership, communication approach, internal and external support, etc.

I didn't list size above or funding, but think that might be a consequence or result of some fundamental attributes that result in funding or growth of support.

Comment: Rate of change of vote/parlament-post share seems like the only useful metric.

Comment: For US specifically, FiveThirtyEight has generic congressional ballot measure that seems to work pretty well as a predictive model.

Comment: This probably does need a location attached, since things like public statements of finances and membership vs voter affiliation will differ in different political systems.

Comment: Perhaps you might clarify "health". Do you mean ability to get things done through government or maybe the ability to accurately represent their membership or make their people feel included?